# Scroll through multiple pdf from folder

Tags: pdf, scrolling

I have multiple pdf-files in a folder - I would like to scroll through all the files so they seem like one pdf.

Merging the files to one file is not an option as it should be done "on the fly" from a intranet webservice.

I was thinking of something like a "pdf-index" file holding the path to each pdf-file and calling the data when scrolling through.

A webservice (php) importing the files and showing them nested for scroll could also be an option.

Comment: So it should be only via a webservice and not a PDF reader? Also, if it matters, which OS?

Comment: The clients is on a Windows platform. They will be accessing it through a webservice - but with access to the network share where the files is located.

Answer (score -1):

Below is an autohotkey script that works in Windows to accomplish your task.  You'll neeed to modify the program to fit your pdf folder and pdf reader.

```
;This Autohotkey program loops through pdf files in a specified folder, by pressing "f" for forward, "r" for reverse, and "x" for exit. 
; You'll need the freeware autohotkey installed and to save this text file program with an .ahk extension.  You will also
; need to change the pdf viewer exe files below to that of your machines own pdf reader, as well as specify the folder
;containing your pdfs. 

Folder := "C:\"  ; <----------------------SPECIFY FOLDER HERE CONTAINING PDF FILES IN QUOTES


FileList =  ; Initialize to be blank.

FileCount := 0

Loop, %Folder%*.pdf {

    FileList = %FileList%%A_LoopFileLongPath%`n 

    FileCount++

                    }


Array := StrSplit(Filelist,"`n")

FileIndex := 1

StartNewPDF:

MsgBox,,, Opening PDF File %FileIndex% of %FileCount%,0.7

 FileToOpen=% Array[FileIndex]


;  v---------------------------------SPECIFY PATH and *.exe FILE OF PDF READER

 Run, "C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe" 

"%FileToOpen%"

 Input, OutputVarx, L1 ,, frx

if (OutputVarx="f")

{

   FileIndex := 1 + Mod(FileIndex - 1 + 1, FileCount)

}

if (OutputVarx="r")

{

   If (FileIndex=1)

     FileIndex = FileCount

   Else FileIndex := FileIndex - 1

}

if (OutputVarx="x")

{

;    v-------------SPECIFY *.exe FILE OF YOUR PDF READER HERE

   Process,Close,PDFXCview.exe

   ExitApp

}

;      v-------------SPECIFY *.exe FILE OF YOUR PDF READER HERE

Process,Close,PDFXCview.exe

Sleep, 100

Goto, StartNewPDF
```